# Dependency decorator with no duplictates

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

In a code below i have written depends decorator which just takes as a parametr some functions and call them before calling decorated function. So when when i use this script i get on output:

```
using f
using g
using f
using h
```

But now there comes my question. How to do it not to duplicate dependencies? So when i use h(), f() will be called just once? I tried to remove duplicates form functs, but for example for h() it's containing wapper and f(). Should I collect them in other way?

```
class depends(object):
    functs = []
    def __init__(self, *f):
        self.functs = []
        for i in f:
            self.functs.append(i)

    def __call__(self, fun):
        def wrapper():
            for i in self.functs:
                i()

            return fun()
        return wrapper

def f():
    print 'using f'

@depends(f)
def g():
    print 'using g'

@depends(g, f)
def h():
    print 'using h'

h()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python already has something like this already built into its `super` calling mechanism. However, to take advantage of `super`, you have to turn your dependencies into base classes:

```
def depends(*deps):
    def deco(func):
        def __new__(self):
            super(Dependency, self).__new__(self)
            return func()
        Dependency = type('Dependency', deps, {'__new__': __new__})
        return Dependency
    return deco


@depends(object)
def f():
    print 'using f'


@depends(f)
def g():
    print 'using g'


@depends(g, f)
def h():
    print 'using h'

h()
# using f
# using g
# using h
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remember processed dependencies globally, for example in a class variable, see `depends.done` here:

```
class depends(object):
    done = []
    def __init__(self, *f):
        self.functs = f

    def __call__(self, fun):
        def wrapper():
            for i in self.functs:
                if i not in depends.done:
                    i() 
                    depends.done.append(i)

            return fun()
        return wrapper

def f():
    print 'using f'

@depends(f)
def g():
    print 'using g'

@depends(g, f)
def h():
    print 'using h'

h()
```

Comment: I'd say it should be an instance variable, otherwise you can use dependencies only once, globally.

Comment: That's what I though was needed, wasn't it?

Comment: ...but you have a class variable, which will be shared for all instances of the class, i.e. for all uses of the decorator. I don't think that's the desired behavior.

Comment: @Ber what do you think the desired bahaviour was, then?

Comment: I think it should be done per decorated function. Independent functions should not influence each other. The decorator might be used on more than one group of related function.

Comment: I suggest you read the question again. The question was not about independent functions, quite opposite, it was about dealing with the functions' dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check wether any of the dependency function has been decorated in this way, and exclude their dependencies from the ones for the currently decorated function.

This check needs to be done recursively.

It becomes much more difficult if you also use other decorators.

I really wonder why and how this construct is used.